# Вывод количества записей, с определенным параметром

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Добрый день! Есть база данных (`data`), в ней 2 записи с одинаковым полем `author` (допустим автор - `test`). При выполнении:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM data WHERE author = 'test'");
$result2 = count($result2);
echo $result2;
```

Выводит почему-то **1**, а не **2** (т.е. в таблице же 2 записи). В чём может быть проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста!

P.S. Если выполнить запрос в `phpmyadmin`, то спокойно выдает **2**.

**UPD.** count - такого ключа нету. Есть ключ `[count(*)]`, но при нём возникает ошибка:

> `Parse error: parse error, unexpected '*', expecting ')' in ...`

Comment: Не count($result2), а $result2['count']. Ну и mysql_fetch_assoc до этого.

Comment: Обновил вопрос..

Comment: count(*) as count

Comment: Работает, спасибо! Но больше подходит mysql_num_rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo $rows;
```

З.Ы. и не нужен `count(*)`

Comment: Большое спасибо! Как то и забыл про mysql_num_rows...

Comment: Если саму инфу из записей выводить не надо, то так делать не стоит, надо `count(*)`.

Comment: Таким запросом получаются все записи таблицы, что более ресурсо-затратно и в частном случае не нужно. Лучше использовать count(*), получить одну запись содержащим количество, чем получить все записи и получить их количество.

Answer (score 4):

SELECT count(*)  работает очень быстро. Много быстрее выгрузки.

Надо писать так:

```
Select count(*) as `count`....
```

тогда количество будет:

```
$result2 = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);

$final_count = $result2['count'];
```

Comment: обратите внимание на mysql_fetch_XXXX - это очень полезная функция. Без нее извлечение информации из RESOURCE очень проблемная задача.

Кстати о скорости: ответ @Palmervan хорош в том случае, если вам нужно ЕЩЕ И выгрузить данные. Если только посчитать, пользуйтесь COUNT: сэкономите, причем частенько не только на спичках.

Answer (score 1):

Хмм... А что быстрее - получить из базы сначала все записи , и потом посчитать их количество, или запросом получить количество записей удовлетворяющих условию?

ПО мне так лучше зделать запрос

```
SELECT count(*) FROM data WHERE author = 'test'
```

Comment: Вы читали вопрос? Запрос делал, но потом выводиться кол-во записей - 1, а не 2.

Comment: Потому что делаете неправильно. Ответ на то как правильно делать есть на этой странице.

Comment: "Запрос делал, но потом выводиться кол-во записей - 1, а не 2." Вы получаете 1 запись в результате работы запроса. Эта запись содержит число "количество записей в таблице data, где author равен 'test'".